# Jackson ObjectMapper add deserialized List<Object> and register module overwrite the old one

Tags: java, list, jackson, deserialization

I have two Json objects that return lists with different data, so I created two `StdDeserializer` one for each object

ProductDeserialized

```
public class ProductDeserialized extends StdDeserializer<List<Product>> {
   @Override
    public List<Product> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      // implementation
    }
```

and OrderDeserialized

```
    public class OrderDeserialized extends StdDeserializer<List<Order>> {
        @Override
        public OrderBook deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      // implementation
      }
    }
```

and this is `ProductDeserialized`

```
public class ProductDeserialized extends StdDeserializer<List<Product>> {

    public ProductDeserialized(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        List<Product> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();

        node.forEach(jsonNode -> {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setId(jsonNode.get("id").asText());
            // implementation
            listProduct.add(p);
        });

        return listProduct;
    }
```

When I register the deserializers created in the module

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(List.class, new ProductDeserialized(Product.class));
module.addDeserializer(List.class, new OrderDeserialized(Order.class));
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Only the last one works, in practice it overwrites `addDeserializer` added previously

So in this case it works only `OrderDeserialized`, overwrite `ProductDeserialized`

This happens because I use `List.class` in `addDeserializer(List.class, ....)` and register 2 times List but with 2 different JsonDeserialized

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working as expected as if there are 2 different `Deserializer` for the same type `List` how it will be determined that which `Deserializer` needs to apply. So, overriding is more logical. However, you use multiple types of Deserializer using annotation `@JsonDeserialize` over the setter.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=ProductDeserializer.class)
public void setProducts(List<Product> value) {
   this.products = products;
}

@JsonDeserialize(using=OrderDeserializer.class)
public void setOrderss(List<Order> value) {
   this.orders = orders;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A particular object mapper instance should know a unique way to deserialize objects of a particular type. If you specify more than one, how would it choose the deserializer to use? If you need to deserialize in two different ways you should define 2 different object mappers.